# Android set session expired to all activities at once

Tags: android, session, alarmmanager, session-timeout, android-alarms

I have a method that checks if the user has internet connection, and if he doesn't he has 24h to get online again, if not the app should stop and take the user to the login activity, it is working, but the problem is, I'm calling this method in the first activity after the login, so the code runs only in that activity, I need a way to call it in the whole app without having to instantiate it in each activity, is there a way to do that? how?
Any help will be appreciate!

here is the code:

```
public void checkConnection(){

        Repositorio mRepositorio = new Repositorio(getApplicationContext());


        SecurePreferences mSessao = new SecurePreferences(getApplicationContext(), "sessao");
        CredencialModel mCredencialModel = mRepositorio.getCredencialPorId(Integer.valueOf(mSessao.getString("id_credencial")));


        try {

            Date dNow = new Date();
            String dt = String.valueOf(mCredencialModel.getUltimo_sincronismo());  // Start date
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // number of days to add
            dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());  // dt is now the new date

            Date lastConnection = sdf.parse(dt);
            Date dateNow = sdf.parse(sdf.format(dNow));

            if(!mRepositorio.temConexao() && (lastConnection.before(dateNow))){

                fnTrocarUsuario();

            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }






    }


private void fnTrocarUsuario() {

        SecurePreferences mSessao = new SecurePreferences(getApplicationContext(), "sessao");
        mSessao.clear();

        // After logout redirect user to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


        // Staring Login Activity
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step-1 :** Create base activity like this,

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

**Step-2 :** Put your checkConnection() method inside this class.

**Step-3 :**  Use BaseAcitivity and extend for your any activity in your app and call particular method.

```
public class YourActivity extends BaseActivity {
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: that is fine, but I have 18 activities, and some of them already extends FragmentActivity, and others ActionBarActivity, how can I manage that? I'm very new to android development

Comment: One suggestion I can think of now is to make it static method.

Answer (score 0):

You should register to listen for activity lifecycle events, via the Application.  More info here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)

Then in the onActivityResumed callback you can check for the connection.